# How can I have a github hook push from github enterprise out to another git repo?

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, github-enterprise

Problem:
We're using GitHub Enterprise for our enterprise development, which means accessing the code from outside (to hook in other services, etc) is problematic.

Idea:
We want to use VSTS to do things w/ the source in our GitHub repo. So I want to create a git hook in my GitHub Enterprise repo that will, after any commit, `git push -f` the repo out to a VSTS instance.

I'm reading about hooks, etc, but I think that the problem is it seems the hooks are always executed on the client? eg: `git` exe on the user's machine is what processes hooks & does the work, not on the server-side (destination repo).

That being said, anybody know of a way you can do a GitHub hook or git hook that will accomplish what I want? I've got the Personal Access Token for VSTS ready to go and have tested the necessary commands locally...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git hooks in general are executed both on the client and on the "server", depending on the hook. For example, the `post-update` hook is executed on a remote repository in response to receiving the result of a `git push` operation.

However, when using a hosted service like GitHub (or BitBucket, or anything else, really), you can't run arbitrary scripts in response to repository operations (because that would be substantial security implications that nobody in their right mind would want to deal with).

A hook *on github* can only send an HTTP `POST` request to another web service. A typical solution to your question is to have a web service receive that POST request, and then ultimately trigger a `git pull` on your server.  You can find the GitHub documentation on hooks at https://help.github.com/articles/about-webhooks/.

Comment: Thanks. I was starting to hone in on this myself... Unfortunately doesn't work for me due to the firewall restrictions of this being an **Enterprise** GitHub instance :(

Comment: That doesn't necessarily rule out this solution.  There are a variety of ways to deliver notifications asynchronously in a manner that complies with local security restrictions.  It really depends on the details of your particular situation (which, if you want to explore, would probably be worth a new question).